# Semantic-UI modal background image

Tags: css, modal-dialog, background-image, semantic-ui

Can Semantic-UI Modal have a background image?

```
<modal ng-model="dc.show_leaderboard" class="leaderBoard">
   <i class="close icon" ng-click="dc.close_modal()"></i>
   <div class="header">Header</div>
</modal>
```

css :

```
.leaderBoard{
  background: url('/assets/images/0011mainBG_SmallRobotBG_overlay1364x768.png') no-repeat !important;
  width: 200px;
  left: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not reference in the documentation, however A model can

1. contain image content
2. vary in sizes
3. use the entire size of the screen

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/definition

But by some css customization we can

**You can try this for image background**

```
 <style>
  .modal {
    background:url('Your path to image')   !important;
   width:200px !important;
   }
 </style>
   <div class="ui view modal  inverted " >
         <div class="header" style="background:none;">User Deletion ?</div>
          <div class="content" style="background:none;">

            <p><?php echo __('Are you sure you want to delete ?'); ?></p>
         </div>
     <div class="actions" style="background:none;">
         <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
         <div class="ui approve button">OK</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**To use a colored background :**

```
     <div class="ui view modal red inverted segment" >
          <div class="header" style="background:none;">User Deletion ?</div>
          <div class="content" style="background:none;">
             <p><?php echo __('Are you sure you want to delete ?'); ?></p>
         </div>
       <div class="actions" style="background:none;">
         <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
         <div class="ui approve button">OK</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```